# Calculation on outcome of For Loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running a For Loop on an Objectives table to list all Key Result scores. The Key Result score is a calculation from several columns in the Key Results table.

**Problem:** I want to add an average score from all Key Result scores to the objectives for loop.

Objective 1

- Key results score 1
- Key results score 2
- Key results score 3

Average: **xxx**

Objective 2

- Key results score 1
- Key results score 2
- Key results score 3

Average: **xxx**

**Question:** The below snippet works to get all the scores, but I don't know how to average these scores?

```
<% @objectives.each do |objective| %>
  <% objective.keyresults.each do |keyresult| %>
    <%= number_to_percentage((keyresult.scores.maximum("score") - keyresult.start_score) / (keyresult.target - keyresult.start_score) * 100, precision: 0)  %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on the sort of average you want, but something like this would work:

```
<% @objectives.each do |objective| %>
  <% total_score = 0 %>
  <% objective.keyresults.each do |keyresult| %>
    <% score = (keyresult.scores.maximum("score") - keyresult.start_score) / (keyresult.target - keyresult.start_score) %>
    <% total_score += score %>
    <%= number_to_percentage(score * 100, precision: 0)  %>
  <% end %>
  <%= "Average: #{number_to_percentage(total_score / objective.keyresults.size * 100, precision: 0)}" %>
<% end %>
```

However ... you *REALLY* shouldn't be doing these calculations in the view as you appear to be. This is business logic, and belongs either in a model somewhere or perhaps in a service object.

Comment: This worked, although it's indeed in the view. Very new to ruby or coding in general. Can you give me any direction where to find more on how to define these calculations in a model and then return outputs in the view?

Comment: It's difficult to give advice around that without seeing the rest of your code. It depends how you're fetching the records in the first place really. If it's a simple `find` then you can provide a class method on your model that does the find and returns the calculated results you need rather than the records. Alternatively, if the source of the records is more complex, you can just write another ruby class that accepts a set of records, and processes the results out of them for you. Try this article on services - https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services